# How to group orders by Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a order details table and I want to find the sum of price by each date and display them as

**For Ex**

```
   count   sum            date 
    5      619.95        2015-11-19
    3      334.97        2015-11-18
    4      734.96        2015-11-18
    5      1129.95       2015-11-18
```

I have written the query for getting the `count` and `sum` as

```
select count(id), sum([price])
from [OrderDetails]
where [date]between '2015-10-29 05:15:00' and '2015-11-09 00:01:00'
group by datepart(day,[date])
```

But not able to achieve with date. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your column called `date` has both a date and time component.  I would suggest converting it to a date, for both the `select` and `group by`:

```
select count(id), sum(price), cast([date] as date) as thedate
from OrderDetails
where [date] between '2015-10-29 05:15:00' and '2015-11-09 00:01:00'
group by cast([date] as date) 
order by thedate;
```

Note:  `date` is a poor name for a column, because it is the name of a built-in type.

Comment: @DheerajPatnaik . . . Is there a reason why you unaccepted this answer?

Answer (score 4):

You need to include what you are grouping on in the `SELECT` portion of your query:

```
select count(id), sum([price]), datepart(day,[date]) as [date]
from [OrderDetails]
where [date] between '2015-10-29 05:15:00' and '2015-11-09 00:01:00'
group by datepart(day,[date]);
```